# Serving keras model with tensorflow serving error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I have created a model using keras which is working locally. But after upgrade of tensorflow to the `2.17.0` I start receiving strange error on the tsserve side.

Model was serialized so:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# tf.version.VERSION == 2.17.0

tf.saved_model.save(
    model,
    export_dir="../models/jager/61",
    #signatures={"serving_default": export_model(preprocessor,model)},
)
```

Serving model I am using docker image of `tensorflow/serving:nightly` (tried also with latest, but it has tensor flow version `2.14.0` only)

```
    root@23556ef83203:/# tensorflow_model_server --version
    TensorFlow ModelServer: 0.0.0+nightly.sha.no_git
    TensorFlow Library: 2.17.0
```

After sending predict request to the model I receive some format error:

> Could not find variable sequential_20/dense_41/bias. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Resource localhost/sequential_20/dense_41/bias/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.\n\t [[{{function_node __inference_serving_default_474794}}{{node sequential_20_1/dense_41_1/add/ReadVariableOp}}]]

This looks like a version conflict, but I tried a lot of different versions with similar errors.

Comment: did you try importing keras from `tf-2.17.0` and saved the model? It seems like a versioning issue

Comment: I have imported model from tf 2.17 , yes. And on the same TF environment i am able to load and call this model

Comment: The issue is tensorflow serving image has `tf 2.14`,
you can either create your own docker image using `tf 2.17` or downgrade your tf to `2.14` and try it again?